# jQuery AJAX success for certain form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the following code to submit multiple forms via AJAX:

```
var formData = $(this).closest('.bookroom1, .bookroom2, .bookroom3, .bookroom4, .bookroom5').serializeArray();
formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: AJAX_URL,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.status == 'success') {
            $('.bookroom1, .bookroom2, .bookroom3, .bookroom4, .bookroom5')[0].reset();
        }       
        $('.booking-main').html(response.content);
        $('.booking-side-response').html(response.sidebar); 
    }
});
```

I want to add some JavaScript in the success/response function but only for a particular form e.g.

```
if ( .bookroom5 ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Does anyone know the best approach to doing this other than creating separate $.ajax functions for each form?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What is the purpose of the Ajax call? Validation? Storage of the forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $form = $(this).closest('.bookroom1, .bookroom2, .bookroom3, .bookroom4, .bookroom5');
var formData = $form.serializeArray();
formData.push({
    name: this.name,
    value: this.value
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: AJAX_URL,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        if ($form.hasClass('bookroom5')) {
            alert('you have used form bookroom5')
        }
    }
});
```

Save the form before then use it later to check the class